# Does the Diophantine equation $x^2 + y^2 = 12x +7$ have any solution?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does the Diophantine equation $x^2 + y^2 = 12x +7$ have any solution?

Could anyone describe to me what to do in this type of nonlinear Diophantine equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $x^2+y^2=12x+7$ can be written as $(x-6)^2+y^2=43$, and $43\equiv -1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Note that once you have rewritten your equation to "Sum of two squares equals some integer", since that integer is small enough ($43$), one can also conclude that there are no solutions through exhaustive search. One does not really need modular arithmetic at that stage.

Answer (score 7):

Studying the equation modulo $4$, we see that there can be no solutions, as $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both either $0$ or $1$, and can thus never sum to $12x + 7\equiv 3$.

Looking at a few simple modular congruences like this (especially modulo anything that actually appears in the equation, so that terms disappear) is a good way to exclude the existence of solutions in many cases. It can never be used (by itself) to prove the existence of solutions. And even for equations that have no solutions, modular arithmetic isn't always the way to come to that conclusion. But it's a simple tool that gets the job done often enough.

Comment: +1 for the tip in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2+y^2=12x+7$$

$$(x-6)^2+y^2=43$$
Since 43 is not sum of two squares the equation does not have any integer solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When I first looked at this question I misread the equation as:

$$x^2+y^2=12z+7$$

But in fact that more general Diophantine equation has no solution since $12z+7=4(3z+1)+3 \equiv3\pmod4$ while $x^2$ and $y^2$ must each be congruent to $0$ or $1 \pmod 4$. So *in this case* it's as easy to prove impossibility for a more general equation as for the particular case (ie $z=x$).

A lesson that can be drawn is that if both sides of a Diophantine equation are subject to modular constraints on the values they can take, then *sometimes* this is sufficient to prove impossibility, regardless of the variables on each side.